# API error no parameters when there are parameters given

Tags: php, laravel, parameters

This is the error I'm getting, as you can see there is a parameter in the URL, but the error says there weren't any parameters given. Can anbody help me out?

> Client error: `PUT https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/devices/d38237721?alias=laptop-test` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
>   {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"no parameters were given.","error_code":1}

This is my code

```
public function update($device_id, $options)
{
    $token = 'thereisatokenhere';

    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/']);
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'Accept-Language' => 'en-US',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ];


    $response = $client->request('PUT', 'devices/' . $options['device_id'], [
        'headers'         => $headers,
        'form_params'            => [
            'alias' => $options['alias'],
        ],
    ]);

    $response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

    $deviceIdsAPI = $response['devices'];

    return $deviceIdsAPI;
}
```

2nd

```
 $request = new Request('PUT', 'https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/devices/' . $options['device_id'], ['alias' => $options['alias']]);
        $response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 2, 'headers' => $headers]);
```

Comment: As it's a PUT request shouldn't the params be submitted as body payload data instead of get variables?

Comment: @user3574492 How would I do that, I've added my code to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a PUT request in Guzzle:

```
$client->put('devices/' . $options['device_id'], [
    'body'            => [
        'alias' => $options['alias'],
        'other_field' => '123'
    ],
    'headers'         => $headers,
    'allow_redirects' => false,
    'timeout'         => 5
]);
```

**Update:**

In the latest version (Guzzle 6) it should be like this:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$request = new Request('PUT', 'http://httpbin.org/put', ['test' => '123']);
$response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 2, 'headers' => $headers]);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152906/how-do-i-send-parameters-for-a-put-request-in-guzzle-5) answer and here is the official [Guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#body)

Comment: Still doesn't work, now I'm getting this error: Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request.

Comment: See my update. Try that. Also post the request code.

Comment: I've added the new code to the post, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to post files to the server?

Comment: I'm updating device details from a Teamviewer device to their api.

Comment: Tried that too, but then it gives this error. Client error: `POST https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/devices/d38237721` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/devices/d38237(truncated...)

Comment: I've updated the first answer again. I put the body first and then headers second. Try that.

Comment: Also what headers are you passing through?

Comment: I've edited my post again, now I'm getting this error: Client error: `PUT https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/devices/d348976732` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: a. Path '', line 0 (truncated...)

Comment: Okay.. It seems like an inconsistency with Guzzle v6. Try my edited code above. (Second part). I have tested locally with that PUT request and it works fine.

Comment: If you do  `dd($response->getBody());` what shows? Did you replace the `'test' => '123'` with your actual body params?`

Comment: Added a new code part in the post, but now I'm getting the no parameter error again.

Comment: What does `dd($response->getBody());` return?

Comment: Uhm nothing?... Where do I need to put it? I have it on the last line.

Comment: just put it straight after the `$response = $client->send(....` line. If it doesn't reach that then its something that your api is intercepting. So maybe refer to the api docs.

Comment: Still getting nothing lol. This is the request according to the documentation: PUT /api/v1/devices/d12345
Content-Type: application/json
{"description" : "Swan Terminal",
 "policy_id": "5d93f008-3b1f-8472-8555-3549d5a68092" }

Comment: I can't see `device_id` anywhere? Also what actual error are you getting? can you post it?

Comment: Its a parameter that is in the function. Updated the code again

Comment: And this is the error: Client error: `PUT https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/devices/d348976732` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: a. Path '', line 0 (truncated...)

Comment: Try this:

`$request = new GuzzleRequest('PUT', 'http://httpbin.org/put');`
        

`$response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 2, 'headers' => $headers, ['body' => ['test' => 'test']]]);`

Comment: if that doesn't work remove the `body` key from the request and send as flat array `['test' => 'test']`

Comment: GuzzleRequest is not found.

Comment: Oops change `GuzzleRequest` to `Request`

Comment: Again no parameters given, also changed 'body' to 'form_params'

Comment: Then its something at the api end. I've tested this put request and it works fine, gives me a 200 response back.

Comment: There was a connectivity issue identified with TV about a hour ago, so maybe when it's back up again it works.